# Почему не выполняется условие?

Tags: javascript

```js
var a = prompt("Загадка:зимой и летом одним цветом?");
if (a = "ель" || "Ель") {
  alert("правильно");
} else {
  alert("неправильно");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

У Вас две ошибки

1. Вы перепутали оператор сравнения (`==`) и оператор присваивания (`=`)
2. Вы совершенно неправильно используете оператор ЛОГИЧЕСКОЕ ИЛИ (`||`)

Должно быть так

```js
var a = prompt("Загадка:зимой и летом одним цветом?");
if ((a == "ель") || (a == "Ель")) {
  alert("правильно");
} else {
  alert("неправильно");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Присваивание:

```
a="ель"
```

Сравнение:

```
a == "ель"
```

Comment: Спасибо!я только учусь)Немогли бы скинуть правильный код!!